# iPhone - UIView animation problem in viewDidLoad / viewDidAppear

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

I have a UIView that contains a subview called menuView managed by a MenuViewController.

I wrote that code :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [self.menuView setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.menuView.frame, 0.0, self.menuView.frame.size.height)];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"SomeAnimation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.menuView cache:YES];           
    [self.menuView setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.menuView.frame, 0.0, -self.menuView.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];   // tried at begining too
}
```

But when loaded, no animation is visible... I also tried with viewWillAppear with no change.

it is called outside MenuViewController with :

```
- (IBAction) showMenu
{
    MenuViewController* menuController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu" bundle:nil];];
    [self.view addSubview:menuController.view];
//    [menuController release];   for try
}
```

What's the problem ?

P.S. : What I want to do is when the view is displayed, some part of that view (the menuView) move. That view (partially transparent) is intended to cover a superview that is owned by another ViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you calling the viewDidAppear method from your view controller? Some controllers, such as the UINavigationController, will take care of that, but if you're using a custom controller, you'll need to call it. Typically, you would call viewWillAppear, then add the view, the call viewDidAppear.

So your code block would be:

```
- (IBAction) showMenu
{
    MenuViewController* menuController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu" bundle:nil];];
    [menuController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:menuController.view];
    [menuController viewDidlAppear:YES];
    [menuController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that self.menuView is actually properly initialized and is not nil?

Comment: Uhh, yes, it is not nil... but viewDidAppear is not triggered... See my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should first call the super initialization of your method ?

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated]
```

Comment: Stupid I am. See my EDIT. But that does not change the problem. Still no animation nor viewDidAppear trigger problem.

Comment: I'd advise putting the viewDidLoad super first too.